# Numpy giving the wrong Fourier transform of sine functions

Tags: matlab, fourier, fft

I'm using numpy's FFT to calculate the Fourier transform of \$\cos(\omega_0t)\$ and plot it.  By using the definition we can derive its Fourier transform as below:

\begin{equation}
X_3(j\omega) = \pi (\delta(\omega - \omega_0) + \delta(\omega + \omega_0))
\end{equation}

According to the equation above I expect to see 2 peaks. One at \$\omega_0\$ and another at \$-\omega_0\$.  For some reason both Numpy and MATLAB plot these peaks at \$\frac{\omega_0}{2\pi}\$ and \$-\frac{\omega_0}{2\pi}\$ respectively.

What is the reason for this operation?

Comment: You're not seeing the *wrong* result, you're *expecting* the wrong result. This looks 100% correct. You're just not using normalized frequencies in what you're expecting (which you'll have to do, this is discrete-time, not continuous-time!).

Comment: Without seeing your actual code (so we can point to the documentation for the specific functions you're using) it's hard to give a more detailed answer than what Marcus provided above.

Comment: w0 = 2*pi*f0 so that is what I would expect.

Comment: There is no such thing as \$ \omega_0 \$ or frequency in a FFT because FFT has no idea what the sample rate is. It only cares about ratio between signal frequency and sampling frequency.

Comment: To express the frequency scale in Hz